# android CollapsingToolbarLayout scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image]

How can i create layout like this with CollapsingToolbarLayout and Toolbar?
First,
HEADER2 and CONTENT scroll up.
When top of CONTENT reach HEADER's bottom make HEADER scroll up.
Then HEADER_PIN is visible and only CONTENT scroll.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?? Google ??

Comment: yes. but i can't. How i change Toolbar from pin to parallax programmatically??

Comment: refer this :http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/